# openpyxl: DataValidation not showing dropdown

Tags: python, openpyxl

I basically copied the example on `DataValidation` using `openpyxl` from the docs (https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/validation.html).

The only difference is that I set the `showDropDown` arg to `True`. Unfortunately, this doesn't make any difference, i.e. when I open the Excel sheet, I don't see the dropdown menu. In fact, it has not been enabled at all (compare screenshot).

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl.worksheet.datavalidation import DataValidation

# Create the workbook and worksheet we'll be working with
wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active
# Create a data-validation object with list validation
dv = DataValidation(
    type="list", formula1='"Dog,Cat,Bat"', allow_blank=True, showDropDown=True
)
# Optionally set a custom error message
dv.error = "Your entry is not in the list"
dv.errorTitle = "Invalid Entry"
# Optionally set a custom prompt message
dv.prompt = "Please select from the list"
dv.promptTitle = "List Selection"
# Add the data-validation object to the worksheet
ws.add_data_validation(dv)
dv.add(ws["A1"])

wb.save(filename="dropdown_issue.xlsx")
```

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Apparentyl, `showDropDown` is an alias for `hide_drop_down`. Setting `showDropDown=False` will do the trick.

This is confusing! An issue has already been opened some time ago at https://foss.heptapod.net/openpyxl/openpyxl/-/issues/1336.